# What does "leap" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

could you please tell what "leap" means in the context below? May it mean "guessing"?
Story goes about a couple, lady and lord; they secretly kissed in the attic. Later that day, lady went to the library and met there her beloved lord Nicolas and his friend Rock.

> Isabel looked to Rock, who, in mock seriousness, announced, “Lord
> Nicholas is ever the perfect gentleman.” Isabel couldn’t help her
> smile when she returned her attention to Nick and said, “I am afraid I
> find that very difficult to believe.” The words were out before she
> could think better of them, and she was immediately aware of the
> possibility that Rock would read some clandestine event into them. Not
> that such a **leap** would be incorrect.

Sara MacLean "Ten Ways to Be Adored When Landing a Lord"

Thank you!

Comment: A leap of imagination, a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is referring to the assumed 'clandestine event' mentioned in the previous sentence. Isabel is worried that her response:

> "I'm afraid I find that very difficult to believe."

will lead Rock to assume that there were interactions between Isabel and Lord Nicholas. Then she hints to the reader that those assumptions about their interactions would not be wrong. You could read that last sentence like this:

> "Not that those assumptions would be incorrect."